# Problema con Angular BlockUI - (AngularJS - Javascript)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

tengo el siguiente problema, necesito bloquear la UI cuando se subo un archivo y este se esta procesando, para esto utilizo [Angular BlockUI](https://github.com/McNull/angular-block-ui/), pero el problema es que la pantalla se bloquea una vez terminado el proceso y no durante el mismo.

```js
var processData = angular.module('library.process_data', ['blockUI']);

processData.controller('ProcessHomescope$scope', function HomeController($scope, blockUI, blockUIConfig) {
  var elementsTeradata = [];
  $scope.updloadTeradata = function(e) {

    //Bloqueo de UI
    blockUIConfig.delay = 100;
    blockUI.start("Cargando...");

    $timeout(function() {

      var files = e.target.files,
        f = files[0];

      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function(e) {

        var data = e.target.result;

        if (!rABS) {
          data = new Uint8Array(data);
        }

        workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
          type: rABS ? 'binary' : 'array'
        });

        elementsTeradata = saveValues(workbook);

        alert("Ingrese segundo Archivo");

      };

      if (rABS) {
        reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
      } else {
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
      }
      //procesar el archivo
      blockUI.stop();
    }, 0);
  };


  function saveValues(workbook) {

    var elementsData = [];
    var row = [];

    var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];

    var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];

    var limit = XLSX.utils.decode_range(worksheet['!ref']);

    var desired_cell;
    var desired_value;

    for (var x = 0; x <= limit.e.r; x++) {
      for (var j = 0; j <= limit.e.c; j++) {

        var cell_address = {
          c: j,
          r: x
        };

        var cell_ref = XLSX.utils.encode_cell(cell_address);

        desired_cell = worksheet[cell_ref];

        desired_value = (desired_cell ? desired_cell.v : undefined);

        row.push(desired_value);

      }
      elementsData.push(row);
      row = [];
    }


    return elementsData;

  }
});
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div>
      <p>Subir Excel de Teradata</p>
      <input type="file" name="teradata" id="teradata" custom-on-change="updloadTeradata" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: En la ventana de edicion del snippet tienes una seccion de opciones donde seleccionar AngularJS para que te haga la referencia a la libreria. Un saludo

Comment: Probablemente tienes un proceso que no es asincrono y no le da tiempo al blockUI para accionar.

Comment: donde invocas `$scope.updloadTeradata` ?

Comment: Hola @Einer, me podrías explicar lo del proceso asincrono?. El proceso se ejecuta en un solo hilo.

Comment: Hola @Klaimmore lo invoco desde el input del html <input type="file" name="teradata" id="teradata" custom-on-change="updloadTeradata" />

Comment: y que hace el `custom-on-change`?

Comment: @Klaimmore detecta que se elegió un archivo.

Comment: yo creo que simplemente el proceso es muy corto para que lo notes. Prueba disminuyendo el *delay* para que se muestre el bloqueo con la configuracion de [blockUIConfig.delay](https://github.com/McNull/angular-block-ui/#delay)

Comment: El proceso no es corto, se demora unos segundos en procesar según el peso del archivo (en este caso excel), pero la pantalla se bloquea una vez se termina el proceso no durante.

Answer (score 0):

### Procesamiento Sincrono

Muy probablemente el problema sea que el codigo que estas ejecutando es sincrono, en lugar de asincrono.

Intenta darle una oportunidad de ejecucion al bloqueo, dejando que el proceso del archivo se realice en un tiempo posterior en la cola de eventos, vale decir, en lugar de:

```
//Bloqueo de UI
blockUI.start("Cargando...");

//procesar el archivo de forma sincrona

blockUI.stop();
```

Haz algo como:

```
//Bloqueo de UI
blockUI.start("Cargando...");

$timeout(function(){
    //procesar el archivo de forma sincrona

    blockUI.stop();
}, 100);
```

El uso del servicio `$timeout` en lugar de un `setTimeout` es para ejecutar el `blockUI.stop()` dentro del ciclo de eventos de angular. Y el delay del timeout de 100ms fue escogido de forma empirica al realizar pruebas.

### Delay en BlockUI

Tambien configura el delay de blockUI en `0`, de la siguiente forma:

```
processData.config(function(blockUIConfig){
  blockUIConfig.delay = 0;
});
```

Notar que el bloque de configuracion es en el metodo `.config()` del modulo, no en el `controller`.

---

### FileReader

Ahora bien, inspeccionando el codigo en particular donde realizas la carga, al usar el FileReader de la siguiente forma:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
    //procesar archivo de forma sincrona
}
reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
//o
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
```

El metodo onload es en realidad donde estas procesando el archivo y se ejecuta segun la documentacion de [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FileReader) de forma asincrona.

Luego es al final de ese metodo donde debes detener el bloqueo:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
    //procesar archivo de forma sincrona

    $timeout(function(){
        blockUI.stop();
    }, 0);
}
reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
//o
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
```

Notar que nuevamente usamos `$timeout` para llamar a `blockUI.stop()`, esto porque el metodo `onload` no se ejecuta en el ciclo de vida de angular.

[Demo actualizado en plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/s8xbln6CTmtidgUQlF44)

Comment: El problema persiste no me bloquea la UI. Probe cambiando de 0 a 1000ms, ahi bloquea la UI, pero obviamente desaparece al segundo y antes de que termine el proceso. Me podrías explicar como hacer que la función sea asincrona?

Comment: @Aldo Además de dejar la funcion en el timeout, configuraste el delay de blockUI en 0?

Comment: Hola @Klaimmore disculpa la demora, lo configuré y me bloquea la UI solo despues de terminar el proceso,  cuando le agrego el blockUI.stop() solo muestra el icono de cargando y queda bloqueada la UI sin desbloquearse.

Comment: puedes agregar un [mcve] a la pregunta?

Comment: Subí nuevamente el codigo con el blockUIConfig.delay

Comment: Deja el delay en 0, y mueve el `stop` al final del metodo `onload`. Ese onload se ejecuta asincrono y es lo que más demora porque ahi procesas el archivo. Como se ejecuta fuera del ciclo de angular tambien debes agregar un `$timeout` al stop por si solo

Comment: Gracias! @Klaimmore me funciono perfecto